# PHP not giving round value that I'm expecting

Tags: php

I have php code in which I want to check value level.

**I am explaining Value level**

```
999 or below is level 0
1999 or below & higher then 1000 = level 1
2999 or below & higher then 2000 = level 2
3999 or below & higher then 3000 = level 3   so on....
```

I cant figure it out how can I check and do this. I know its all messed because I am using round but I cant figure any other way : `$level = round($v / 1000);`

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$level = 0;
$v = isset($_GET['v']) ? (int)$_GET['v'] : 100;
do {
    $i++;
    $bid  = round($v / 10);
        if ($v > 1000)
        {$bid = 100;}
    $level = round($v / 1000);
    echo "<tr><td>$" . number_format($v) . "</td><td>$" . number_format($bid) . "</td><td>" . $level . "</td></tr>";
    $v = $v + $bid;
} while ($i < 5);
?>
```

**Output is:**

```
$348    $35 0
$383    $38 0
$421    $42 0
$463    $46 0
$509    $51 1
$560    $56 1
$616    $62 1
$678    $68 1
$746    $75 1
$821    $82 1
```

**Output I want is:**

```
$746    $75 0
$821    $82 0
$903    $90 0
$993    $99 0
$1,092  $100    1
$1,192  $100    1
$1,292  $100    1
$1,392  $100    1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [floor()](http://www.php.net) function instead of round().